# Does triboelectric generator made with powder and wire mesh work?

Tags: electrical-engineering, structural-engineering, energy, electrical

[image]

One of the greatest challenges for triboelectric generators is surface charge, which ultimately depends on surface area. Why don't we make one triboelectric layer a powdered form and a crazy forest of conductor wires coated with the other triboelectric material? Then we put this in an enclosed package, and maybe take all the air out to prevent electrostatic breakdown?

The powder will rub against the wire forest and then goes toward the electrode on the left (see picture) and back and forth.

Shouldn't this increase the current (and power) density a great deal?

Is there a reason why almost all research focuses on two flat layers?